# How to post multiple parameters from jquery to controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an existing jquery function where I need to add one more parameter to post to the controller.

```
var form = $("#PackageForm").serialize();

$.post("/Packages/Edit", form, function (data) {
                           if (data.Success) {
                                                ...
                                              }
```

Now, in this code how do I add one more parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append to form data:

```
var form = $("#PackageForm").serialize();
form+= "&myParam="+paramValue;
```